# Move activity indicator dynamically in UITableView in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, uitableview, ios9, uiactivityindicatorview

I am aware of adding the activityIndicator to a certain place in the view, starting and stopping the animation when required. But in certain instances in my app, where the user clicks on a cell(with the title and subtitle), I fetch some data in the background and then show an alert to the user to get some inputs. In all these cases, I just display an activity indicator in the middle, which doesn't look so good. So, I would like to display the activity indicator only at the end of the cell, on which the user clicked. Is there a way to do that?

One thing I could think of is using a custom table View Cell and then explicitly adding an activity indicator there. But is it possible to do the same with a standard title and subtitle cell, and may be dynamically re-positioning the activity indicator based on the position of the cell the user has clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it using UITableViewCell's `accessoryView`

```
var selectedIndexPath : NSIndexPath?

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    // ...

    if (indexPath == selectedIndexPath)
    {
        cell.accessoryView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
        (cell.accessoryView as! UIActivityIndicatorView).startAnimating()
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryView = nil
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
}
```

Comment: It did work. The only change I did was get the cell when didSelectRowAtIndexPath was called like this:
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        cell!.accessoryView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle:      UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
        (cell!.accessoryView as! UIActivityIndicatorView).startAnimating()